# In react native I want to Overlay a textInput out side my app. I have found any package on it

Tags: android, react-native

In react native I want to Overlay a textInput out side my app. I have found package react-native-floating-bubble  but it is only render Image not TextInput if I edit this package android .xml part ImageView to Edit view then it Only render my text input it is not moving and keyboard not opening. Please help me to giving valuable suggestion on it.